# Does it always return the document list in the same order when using the query method in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I use CouchDB to store records in JSON manner.
My question is does it always keep the same order when returning the documents list?

Answer (score 1):

By default, any [view endpoint](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#api-ddoc-view) will return the documents stored in a database in ascending key order. This includes the [_all_docs endpoint](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html), meaning that your documents are sorted by `_id` by default for that endpoint.

If you do not require the documents to be sorted, you can set the `sorted` parameter to `false` to improve performance, but in that case no order is guaranteed.